Use numpad keys for cursor control within Windows Guests on VirtualBox
I would like to use the numpad keys for cursor control within a Window 10 Guest on VirtualBox and I can't get it working with the Numlock ON.
I expect the shortcut [Shift] + [Numpad 1] to do like [End] whatever the Numlock state but I get a 1 with the Numlock ON.
It works without the [Shift] modifier with the Numlock OFF though.
The [Shift] modifier isn't currently used for any VirtualBox shortcuts (which are believe are defaults).
Anyone know what is stopping the [Shift] modifier to override Numlock ?
